# FFMPEG global pattern multiple input formats

Tags: ffmpeg, wildcard

I need to get thumbnails of all images in the directory. Images have formats `.png .jpg .JPG`.

In order to do that I use
`ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -vf scale=320:-1 compressed/img%03d.png`

When I use for it `*.jpg` and then for `*.JPG` the first images are overwritten because numeration starts from zero again.

I am looking for a way how to do a conversion for multiple formats or just for all files in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I made that on *bash*. Pretty ugly way but it is doing what I want as I don't care about output file names.

```sh
for format in jpg JPG png
do
 ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.'$format -vf scale=320:-1 compressed/$format%03d.png
done
```

Comment: Hello herman i want to create slideshow with ffmepg from jpeg and png images will you have idea how to do that  i have solution with only one format at a time like jpg or png but dont have both?

Comment: @Darshanambaliya I think one way to do this is to convert all images to the same format and use [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer). I wrote [the shell script](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Sheogorath2/jBnBd/) for you that does that.